# gmaps.js add DrawingManager control

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps.js

I have a map using [gmaps.js](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/), I want to add a controller to the map that allows the users to draw shapes.

I understand this can be done using google maps api as follows:

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.location[0], pos.location[1]),
    zoom: 3,
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({

    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
      ]
    }});
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
```

but I'm looking for an alternative with gmaps.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gmaps.js doesn't have a method for drawing. But you can create your map with gmaps.js and add drawing manager to it with normal api.

```
var map = new GMaps({
  div: '#map_canvas',
  lat: -12.043333,
  lng: -77.028333
});

var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({

    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
      ]
    }});
  drawingManager.setMap(map.map); // map.map is the reference to original map object
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WCR5L/)

Comment: Thanks mate ... a life saver :))